# Google Compute Engine snapshot of instance with persistent disks attached failed

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a working VM instance that I'm trying to copy to allow redundancy behind google load balancer.
A test run with a dummy instance worked fine, creating a new instance from a snapshot of a running one. 
Now, the real "original" instance have a persistent disk attached and this cause a problem in starting up the cloned instance because of the (obviously) missing persistent disk mount.
Logs from serial console output is as:

`* Stopping cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
* Stopping log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
* Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices[74G[ OK ]
The disk drive for /mnt/XXXX-log is not ready yet or not present.
keys:Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery`

As I understand there is no way to send any of this key strokes to the instance, is there any other way to overcome this issue? I know that I could unmount the disk before the snapshot, but the workflow I would like to instate is creating period snapshots of production servers, so un-mounting disks every time before performing it would require instance downtime (plus all the unnecessary risks of doing an action that would seem pointless).

Is there a way to boot this type of cloned instances successfully, and attach a new persistence disk afterwards?

Is this happening because the original persistent disk is in use, or the same problem would occur even if the original instance is offline (for example due to a failure in which case I would try to created a new instance from a snapshot)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround that I am using to get away from the same issue is that I dont't actually unmount the disk rather just comment out the the mount line in `/etc/fstab` and take the snapshot. This way my instance has no downtime or down disks while snapshoting. (I am using Ubuntu `14.04` as OS if that matters)

Later I fix and uncomment it when I use that snapshot on a new instance.
However you can also look into adding the `nofail` option in the commented line to get a better solution.

By the way I am doing a similar task building a load balanced setup with multiple webserver nodes. Each being cloned from the said snapshot with extra persistent disks mounted for eg uploads,data and logs etc

Comment: Is this happening because the original persistent disk is in use, or the same problem would occur even if the original instance is offline (for example due to a failure in which case I would try to created a new instance from a snapshot)?
**Yes this is happening because original disk is in use, but original instance going offline will still not release it unless you unassign the disk from original instance.**

Comment: Also its possible to send key strokes to instance via serial port. Here are the steps 
1. Enable connecting via serial port on your instance or project
2. Connect to Serial port via cloud web console

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish.  It sounds like you're looking to periodically snapshot the data volumes of a production server so you can clone them later.

In all likelihood, you simply need to sync and fsfreeze to before you make your snapshot, rather than just unmounting/remounting it.  The GCP documentation has a basic example of this in the [Snapshots documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots).

Comment: Yes, periodic backup/cloning is the final aim, and for the attached volumes it works like the link you sent, the problem is the system disk of the instance. As the OS  will expect to have these disks mounted at start up, a cloned instance will never start because the data disk are not be available, as per error above. The only solution I have found at this time is to unmount the data disks, and then do the snapshot. This will allow the cloned disk to start properly, but having to remove the data disks to perform the cloning every time is very inconvenient

Comment: You can add `nofail` to the mount line of the additional disk in `/etc/fstab`. This will do not report errors for the device if it does not exist and consequently the cloned VM will boot up successfully.